# Python command to get last part file

Tags: python

I have .dat file look like:

STEP1
a1   b1
a2   b2
a3   b3

STEP2
a4   b4
a5   b5
.
.
.
STEPn
an   bn
am   bm

Each step has two column (a and b). I need a scrip, which looks last step and gives me "an" and "am"

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What, specifically, are you having an issue with?

Comment: The idea of the site is to ask question about programming, not to ask for someone else do your programming for you. If you have an issue with this script, please be more specific about it.

Answer (score 1):

Something efficient, that even works with very long files (uses almost no memory):

```
with open("data.dat") as f:  # File automatically closed
    for line in f:  # Goes through all the line (no need to store them)
        pass
step, an, bn, am, bm = line.split()  # Splits the last line read (on spaces)
```

If you need to convert numerical values, `int(an)` or `float(an)` work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your steps are on separate lines and that the last line of the file is your last STEP

```
f = open("data.dat", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
last_line = lines[-1]
step, an, bn, am, bm = last_line.split()
```

Comment: This unnecessarily uses memory (the `f.readlines()` part, which loads the whole file into memory).

Comment: Yes I agree. I like your solution.